# correct way to call D3.js object in Drupal module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drupal-7

I am trying to visualize a network using D3 with Drupal 7.x and I don't know what is the right way to refer to D3 within my js file.

So far I can build the json and use a render array to pass it to my js script (and show it in console), but then I fail calling D3.js:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

Here's my js code so far:

```
(function($){
    Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
        attach : function(context, settings) {
            if(Drupal.settings.mymodule.graph_json !== ''){
                // visualize the json
                console.log(Drupal.settings.mymodule.graph_json);
                // create the newtork
                d3.json(Drupal.settings.mymodule.graph_json, function (error, json) {
                if (error){
                    return console.warn(error);
                }
                });
            }
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Should I add a reference in the array? Or since D3.js is in sites/all/libraries/d3 then there is a common way to call it?

Comment: You don't have d3 referenced anywhere, either load it at the top of your html/php file, or call `import /path/to/libraries/d3.js` if you can use es205 modules. [Look here for more methods that may be helpful](https://github.com/d3/d3)

Comment: thank for the comment, I don't have any reference to jQuery either, because Drupal handles that for me... since I have installed the D3 module for Drupal, I am wondering if there is a way Drupal is handling a D3 reference in some way...

Comment: You are specifying jQuery tho in the outer function. In the wrapper function try `(function($, d3){...}(jQuery, d3))`

Comment: I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error if I do like you suggest

Answer (score 0):

According to the statement in the bottom of your question:

> Should I add a reference in the array? Or since D3.js is in sites/all/libraries/d3 then there is a common way to call it?

You have placed the `d3.js` file in the wrong directory `sites/all/libraries/d3.js`. That file should be in the right directory as you can see the screenshot below.

Follow the steps:

- Download the [D3 library](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/download/v5.0.0/d3.zip)
- Extract in `sites/all/libraries/d3/`
- Make sure `d3.js` file is in the right directory `sites/all/libraries/d3/d3.js`

**Screenshot:**

[image]

After that, if you find another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined` the you should read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580958/d3-module-on-drupal-doesnt-show-examples).

This works for me.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: thank, but I already have D3.js in the right folder sites/all/libraries/d3/

Comment: I need to reference d3 in my js script, and I just don't know how to do that... using Drupal.d3 doesn't work

Comment: I answered according to your configuration (`sites/all/libraries/d3.js`) and error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`)... Such error comes only when you configure library into the incorrect directory.

Comment: sorry but that was not my configuration, I have d3.js into sites/all/libraries/d3/ 
don't know if I express my problem correctly, but the issue is how to refer to d3 in my own script