# D3 module on Drupal doesn't show examples

Tags: d3.js, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed D3.js module on Drupal 7.x, enabled the module the D3 views and D3 examples, uploaded d3.js into sites/all/libraries/d3 but when I try to access the examples, like /d3/examples/bar, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined
```

it looks like D3 library is not loaded... I googled a lot but failed to find any hint. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the version `7.x-1.0-alpha3` of [D3 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) then you need to download https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js and replace with `sites/all/libraries/d3/d3.js`. It works for me as in the screenshot.

Make sure the file name must be remain same as `d3.js`.
[image]

For more details: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450349/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-linear-of-undefined#answer-38450683)

I hope that would help you out.

Comment: so this means that we cannot use D3 version higher than 3, despite the fact in the D3 module it says to download the latest version?

Comment: probably not its not mentioned in the module documentation.